# Lorentz transformation of velocity 4-vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity, classical-electrodynamics, lorentz-symmetry

**Question**

Consider two inertial frames of reference, $S$ and $S'$, sharing the $x$-axis. $S'$ is travelling at constant velocity $\vec{v}=v\hat{x}$ from S and at $t=t'=0$, the origins of the two frames coincide.

In frame $S'$, a particle is travelling at constant velocity $\vec{u'}=u'\hat{x}$. At $t'=0$, the particle is at the origin of $S'$.

**(a)**
Calculate the velocity 4-vector $\eta^{\mu}{'}$ of the particle in the frame $S'$.

**(b)** 
Using a suitable Lorentz transformation, determine the velocity 4-vector  $\eta^{\mu}$ of the particle in the frame S.

**(c)** 
Using the component $\eta^{0}$, calculate $u$, the velocity of the particle as observed from frame S, thus deriving the relativistic velocity addition formula:

$u=\frac{u'+v}{1+\frac{u'v}{c^2}}$

**Attempt**

**(a)**
This part is fairly straightforward, I get:

$\eta^{\mu}{'}=\gamma_{u'}(c,u',0,0)$

by differentiating $x^{\mu}{'}$ with respect to proper time and applying the chain rule.

**(b)** This is where I am no longer sure of my work. I decide to use the transformation matrix

$\Lambda^{-1}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   \gamma & \beta \gamma  & 0 & 0 \\
   \beta \gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

with positive signs as this situation is viewed as $S$ travelling away from $S'$ at -v$\hat{x}$ (or, I believe it is the inverse of the standard transformation matrix). We define also $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$.

Then, using [ ] to indicate matrices, I carry out the transformation $[\eta]=\Lambda^{-1} [\eta]'$ and get, via matrix multiplication, the following, where the gamma indices indicate which velocity gamma is a function of:

$\eta^{\mu}=\gamma_v \gamma_{u'} \left( {\begin{array}{c} 
c+v \\
\frac{vu'}{c}+u'\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array} } \right)
$

I'm not really sure if this is correct. I have attempted **(c)** with this solution, equating $\eta^{0}$ from above to $\eta^{0}=\gamma_u c$ but the velocity addition formula didn't drop out.

I appreciate any corrections, hints and guidance! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints :**

1. If you intend to use the matrix $\:\Lambda^{-1}\:$ given in $\:\S(\bf b)\:$  then you must swap the spatial and temporal components of $\:\eta^{\mu}{'}\:$ given in $\:\S(\bf a)$.
2. It's not necessary to work with 3+1-dimensions.Work in 1+1-dimensions.
3. If it's constraint to work with 4 or 2-vectors, then OK. But the exercise could be solved easily directly by the 1+1-Lorentz transformation.
4. The way you try to solve your exercise might demand the difficult case of determining the relation between the $\:\gamma-$factors : $\:\gamma_{\upsilon},\gamma_{u},\gamma_{u'}$.

---

**EDIT A :**

<sup>1+1-Lorentz Transformation $\:S-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow S'\:$

\begin{align}
\text{Spatial} : & \quad x'_{1}=\gamma_{\upsilon}\left(x_{1}-\beta x_{0}\right)
\tag{01a}\\
\text{Temporal} : & \quad x'_{0}=\gamma_{\upsilon}\left(x_{0}-\beta x_{1}\right)
\tag{01b}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
x'_{0}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
=\Lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
x_{0}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}\beta }\gamma_{\upsilon} & \boldsymbol{-}\beta \gamma_{\upsilon}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
 \boldsymbol{-}\beta\gamma_{\upsilon} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}\beta }\gamma_{\upsilon}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
x_{0}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
=\Lambda^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
x'_{0}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\Lambda^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\beta }\gamma_{\upsilon} & \beta \gamma_{\upsilon}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
 \beta\gamma_{\upsilon} & \hphantom{\beta }\gamma_{\upsilon}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
In all above equations we have as first component the spatial with subscript *$_{1}$ and as second component the temporal with subscript *$_{0}$.</sup>

<sup>So for the 2-velocity
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\eta'}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\eta'_{1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\eta'_{0}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
=\gamma_{u'}
\begin{bmatrix}
 u'\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
c\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\ne
\underbrace{
\gamma_{u'}
\begin{bmatrix}
 c\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
u'\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\eta'_{0}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\eta'_{1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\textbf{yours in}\:\boldsymbol{\S(a)} }
\tag{06}
\end{equation}</sup>

---

**EDIT B :**

<sup>Difficult to prove but you must try. If you succeed to prove them I suggest to post them as an answer to your own question herein : 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\gamma_{u'}}{\gamma_{u}}=\gamma_{\upsilon}\left(1-\dfrac{\upsilon\, u}{c^{2}}\right)
\tag{07}
\end{equation}
or for the inverse transformation
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\gamma_{u}}{\gamma_{u'}}=\gamma_{\upsilon}\left(1+\dfrac{\upsilon\, u'}{c^{2}}\right)
\tag{08}
\end{equation}</sup>

---

**EDIT C :**

<sup>Strange or not the easy way to prove equation (07), or equivalently equation (08), is not algebraic. Instead of many pages of algebra I like very much the following game with the $\:\mathrm dt'$s (I post the proof since this doesn't answer your question)</sup>

<sup>So, let a third system $\:S''\:$ attached  to the particle. This system is moving with velocity $\:u'\:$ with respect to $\:S'\:$ and with velocity $\:u\:$ with respect to $\:S$. In system $\:S''\:$ the time $\:t''\:$ is the proper time $\:\tau\:$. In this system let two events 1 and 2, the particle at rest ($\:\mathrm dx''=x''_{2}-x''_{1}=0\:$) at time moments $\:\mathrm t''_{1},\mathrm t''_{2}\:$ apart by the infinitesimal (proper) time interval $\:\mathrm dt''=t''_{2}-t''_{1}=\mathrm d\tau\:$.</sup>

<sup>From the Lorentz Transformation $\:S''\longleftarrow\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow S'\:$
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dt'}{\:\mathrm dt''}=\dfrac{\,\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm d\tau}=\gamma_{u'}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}
and from the Lorentz Transformation $\:S''\longleftarrow\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow S\:$
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\:\:\mathrm dt''}=\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\tau}=\gamma_{u}
\tag{10}
\end{equation}
But from the Lorentz Transformation $\:S'\longleftarrow\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow S\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\,\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm dt}=\gamma_{\upsilon}\left(1-\dfrac{\upsilon\, u}{c^{2}}\right)
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
Dividing (09) by (10) and using (11) we have (07).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response!  
1. I don't quite follow the reasoning, why is that the case?  
2. True, thanks!  
3. Would this involve deriving and applying the velocity addition formula in part (b)? I have thought about this but since I am asked to verify it in part (c), so I presume that I should not use it in part (b).   
4. Correct, I have tried to do this but cannot see an easy way out.

Comment: Thanks, all clear now! I actually realised that I also made a basic matrix multiplication error previously ... Certainly that didn't help either. I now have the relations as shown in edit B, but after a page or two of algebra I cannot see how this might work. See my answer for what I did.

Comment: Re edit C, that's very neat! It would have taken me time to get that. Really appreciate your help and detail - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For part **(c)**, after playing around with the transformed 4-vector a little, I found that the velocity addition formula neatly drops out by dividing the spatial 4-velocity by the its temporal component:

$$ \frac{\eta^1}{\eta^0}=\frac{\gamma_{u}u}{\gamma_{u}c}=\frac{\gamma_v \gamma_{u'}(v+u')}{\gamma_v \gamma_{u'}(c+\frac{vu'}{c})}$$

All gamma factors neatly cancel and multiplying by $c$ yields the velocity addition formula. I'm not sure if this is the method as suggested by the question but it is much simpler than trying to equate the three gammas.