# Why don't these conversions of time between reference frames seem consistent?

Tags: special-relativity, time, velocity, inertial-frames, time-dilation

I am a student and due to school closures I am reading ahead in physics. I have been learning about relativity and I made up a problem for myself. You can see a diagram that I drew below:

[image]

The diagram shows car X travelling at $0.7c$ with respect to car B and $0.5c$ with respect to car A. Car A is travelling at $0.2c $ with respect to car B, where $c$ is the speed of light.

This means, using Lorentz transform, 1 year on car X is equivalent to:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.5^2}}=1.15
$$

1.15 years on car A.

And 1 year on car X is equivalent to:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.7^2}}=1.40
$$

1.40 years on car B.

This means that 1.15 years on car A should be the same as 1.40 years on car B.

So if we were to use the Lorentz transform we should get the same answer but instead we get:

$$
\frac{1.15}{\sqrt{1-0.2^2}}=1.17
$$

We get 1.17 years on car B is the same as 1.15 years on car A. I don't understand what I have done wrong. Could you help me why this problem arises?

It is also worth noting that if I was to use a different method it would work. If I was to convert the time for car X into the time for car A then convert the time for car A into the time for car B, it would work. But I don't understand why this method works. In fact, I believe that method shouldn't work. This is because car X will be moving at 0.7c with respects to B still so 1 years on car X should be the same as 1.40 years on car B.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The contradiction is in the setup. It is **impossible** that those three relative velocities can simultaneously be true.

You can't just add relative velocities together directly in special relativity. If an observer moving at velocity $v$ measures, in their own frame, a velocity $v'$ of some passing object, then a stationary observer would measure the velocity

$$u=\frac{v+v'}{1+\frac{vv'}{c^2}}$$

If car A is moving at $0.2c$ with respect to car B, and car X is moving at $0.5c$ in the same direction with respect to car A, then car X **must** be moving at roughly $0.64c$ with respect to car B, **not** $0.7c$.

Comment: Using velocity-composition alone does not resolve the key issue, which is that time-dilation factors aren’t multiplicative.

Comment: @robphy The fact that time-dilation factors aren't multiplicative can be directly derived from the velocity-composition law. And that doesn't address what's actually wrong with the question's reasoning, which is that it has assumed, at the start, conditions which are impossible.

Comment: Couldn't those relative speeds be possible if they aren't all going the same direction?  That is, if A is moving relative to X in a manner such that a component of its velocity is in the opposite direction to the decomposition of B's velocity with respect to X along the same axes then the speeds given become possible.  In fact, there's probably exactly two possible velocity configurations in 2 dimensions that work.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil This is why I specifically said "relative _velocities_", not speeds. The direction does indeed matter.

Comment: @probably_someone For sure, but that's a pretty sneaky addition to the premises, since the question itself seems to treat them only as speeds, even if the diagram does admittedly make it look like they are all parallel. I just feel like you might want to call out that assumption of parallelism somewhere more clearly.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil I don't see where the question seems to treat them only as speeds.

Comment: @probably_someone: You use the term "velocity", but your last paragraph only gives magnitudes. To address Please's point, I think you need to add the phrase "in the same direction" somewhere in there.

Comment: @probably_someone the question just uses numbers, referring to things as travelling 'at 0.2c' for example. Speed and velocity don't really need to be distinguished in 1-d problems most of the time, so this sort of makes sense, but the question never actually indicates anything about the number of dimensions involved. For the stronger claim that these parameters are impossible it would be nice to have something referring to that just a bit more than just by using the term 'velocity'.  I think it only seems that way to me because I teach, and velocity!=speed is a common mistake I see.

Comment: By which I mean students conflating velocity and speed and e.g. implicitly assuming that because speed is constant acceleration is 0 in rotational kinematics problems.

Answer (score 9):

> The diagram shows car X travelling at 0.7c with respects to car B and 0.5c with respects to car A. Car A is travelling at 0.2c with respects to car B. Where c is the speed of light.

This is impossible. If car X is travelling at a velocity $0.7c$ w.r.t. car B and at a velocity $0.5c$ w.r.t. car A then according to the relativistic addition of velocities, car A would be travelling at a velocity $> 0.2c$.

If the velocities of two objects are $u$ and $v$ w.r.t. an observer then the relative velocity of the first w.r.t. the second is given by

$$\frac{u-v}{1-\frac{uv}{c^2}}$$

In your example, car A and car B are moving with velocities $-0.5c$ and $-0.7c$ respectively in the frame of car X. Thus, the velocity of A w.r.t. B will be given by

$$\frac{-0.5c+0.7c}{1-{(0.5)(0.7)}}$$

which would be obviously not $0.2c$ like you assume.

The morale of the story is that the Newtonian expectations of how velocities get combined don't remain valid in relativity and you need to be careful as to whether your assumptions are internally inconsistent in the purview of relativity.

Comment: As the answer by `@probably_someone` shows, you can also take the relation between the velocities of (X and A) and (A and B) to be true and show that your assumption about the velocity between (X and B) won't hold. The point is that the three assumptions are inconsistent as given, you'd have to modify at least one of them to be consistent with relativity.

Comment: Using velocity-composition alone does not resolve the key issue, which is that time-dilation factors aren’t multiplicative.

Comment: @robphy Good point, I didn't really look closely what OP was doing afterwards. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Although the OP mistakenly used galilean velocity-composition ($v_{AC}=v_{AB}+v_{BC}$)
 instead of special-relativisitic velocity composition ($v_{AC}=\displaystyle\frac{v_{AB}+v_{BC}}{1+v_{AB}v_{AC}}$),
using **special-relativisitic velocity-composition alone
 does not resolve the key issue in the OP.**

---

The key issue is

### time-dilation factors are not multiplicative

Although $\displaystyle\frac{0.5+0.2}{1+(0.5)(0.2)}=\frac{7}{11}\approx0.6363...$,
$$\def\GAM#1{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-{#1}^2}}}
\def\BGAM#1{\displaystyle\frac{#1}{\sqrt{1-{#1}^2}}}
\GAM{0.5}\GAM{0.2}\neq \GAM{\left(\frac{7}{11}\right)}
$$

Instead, 
$\GAM{0.5}\GAM{0.2} + \BGAM{0.5}\BGAM{0.2} = \GAM{\left(\frac{7}{11}\right)}$

Here it is in a form that you can copy-paste into wolframalpha [using implied multiplication]:
(1/sqrt(1-0.5^2))(1/sqrt(1-0.2^2))+(0.5/sqrt(1-0.5^2))(0.2/sqrt(1-0.2^2))-(1/sqrt(1-(7/11)^2))

Or, with an alternate set of velocities...

Although $\displaystyle\frac{0.7-0.5}{1-(0.7)(0.5)}=\frac{4}{13}\approx0.307692...$,
$$\def\GAM#1{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-{#1}^2}}}
\def\BGAM#1{\displaystyle\frac{#1}{\sqrt{1-{#1}^2}}}
\GAM{0.5}\GAM{(\frac{4}{13})}\neq \GAM{ 0.7 }
$$

Instead, 
$\GAM{0.5}\GAM{(\frac{4}{13})} + \BGAM{0.5}\BGAM{(\frac{4}{13})} = \GAM{0.7}$

Here it is in a form that you can copy-paste into wolframalpha [using implied multiplication]:

(1/sqrt(1-0.5^2))(1/sqrt(1-(4/13)^2))+(0.5/sqrt(1-0.5^2))((4/13)/sqrt(1-(4/13)^2))-(1/sqrt(1-(0.7)^2))

---

More generally,
time-dilation factors are not multiplicative--there is an extra factor $$\gamma_{AC}=\gamma_{AB}\gamma_{BC}(1+v_{AB}v_{BC}).$$

These are easier to recognize if you work with rapidities (Minkowski angles), 

where $v_{AC}=\tanh\theta_{AC}$, 
$\gamma_{AC}=\cosh\theta_{AC}$, 
$v_{AC}\gamma_{AC}=\sinh\theta_{AC}$, 
etc...

Since rapidities are additive
$$\theta_{AC}=\theta_{AB}+\theta_{BC},$$
we have
$$\begin{align*}
v_{AC}=\tanh(\theta_{AC})
&=\tanh(\theta_{AB}+\theta_{BC})\\
&=\frac{\tanh\theta_{AB}+\tanh\theta_{BC}}{1+\tanh\theta_{AB}\tanh\theta_{BC}}\\
&=\frac{v_{AB}+v_{BC}}{1+v_{AB}v_{BC}},
\end{align*}
$$
which is the velocity-composition formula.

So, the time-dilation-factor is 
$$\begin{align}\gamma_{AC}=\cosh(\theta_{AC})
&=\cosh(\theta_{AB}+\theta_{BC})\\
&=\cosh\theta_{AB}\cosh\theta_{BC}+\sinh\theta_{AB}\sinh\theta_{BC}\\
&=\cosh\theta_{AB}\cosh\theta_{BC}(1+\tanh\theta_{AB}\tanh\theta_{BC})\\
&=\gamma_{AB}\gamma_{BC}(1+v_{AB}v_{BC}),
\end{align}$$
which is the formula used in the two numerical examples above.
Again, the key issue is that
**time-dilation factors are not multiplicative.**

---

(You may ask
Q: "So, what factors are multiplicative?"
A: the Doppler factors: $k_{AB}=\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1+v_{AB}}{1-v_{AB}}}=e^{\theta_{AB}}$.)

(For a variation of this, have a look at my answer to similar question at
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/326289/148184 )